# SQL query to find duplicate records and discount from COUNT

Tags: sql

I am using below SQL query to count the records.
I would like to discount the duplicate testID after I got the count.

example:

```
select COUNT(*)  from PRODUCT where CLASS_TYPE = 'test'
```

above query give 5 records

```
testID
1234-00-01
1234-00-01
1234-00-02
1234-00-02
1111222233
```

I want to get the count = 5 - duplicate 2 = 3

Is there SQL query I can use to find out the duplicate records, then calculate the final count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below query,

```
select COUNT(distinct testID)  from PRODUCT where CLASS_TYPE = 'test'
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `count(distinct)`:

```
select count(distinct testID)
from product p
where p.class_type = 'test'
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to get the total count and duplicate, you can try this SQL:**

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT testID) as distinct_elements, count(*) as total_elements, 
      (count(*) - count(DISTINCT testID)) as duplicate_elements 
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE CLASS_TYPE = 'test';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct` :

```
select count(distinct col) as Unique_CNT, COUNT(*) as all_CNT  
from PRODUCT 
where CLASS_TYPE = 'test';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
( 
testID VARCHAR(100)   
) 

INSERT INTO #Test
(testID)
VALUES
('1234-00-01'),
('1234-00-01'),
('1234-00-02'),
('1234-00-02'),
('1111222233')

select COUNT(distinct testID) from #Test
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it